# Cannot hide tab content when clicking the same tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I created a simple tab system with panels. It works when I change tabs, but I'm trying to make it so that when you click on the same tab, the corresponding panel should be hidden and the aria attributes should reset, but what I tried doesn't work.

This is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
 if (thisTab.attr('aria-expanded') == 'true') {
            thisTab.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
            thisTab.removeClass('is-active');
            thisTabPanel.attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
  } else {
            thisTab.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
            thisTab.addClass('is-active');
            thisTabPanel.attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.tablist li').attr('role', 'presentation');
  $('.tablist li a').attr({
    "aria-selected": "false",
    "role": "tab",
    "tabindex": "0"
  });


  $('.tablist__panel').attr({
    "aria-hidden": "true",
    "role": "tabpanel"
  });


  $('.tab').attr('id', function(IDcount) {
    return 'tab' + IDcount;
  });

  $('.tab').attr('href', function(IDcount) {
    return '#panel' + IDcount;
  });

  $('.tab').attr('aria-controls', function(IDcount) {
    return 'panel' + IDcount;
  });

  $('.panel').attr('id', function(IDcount) {
    return 'panel' + IDcount;
  });

  $('.panel').attr('aria-labelledby', function(IDcount) {
    return 'tab' + IDcount;
  });


  $(".panel").hide();


  $(function() {

    // Cache selectors
    var tabs = $('.tablist li a'),
      tabPanels = $('.panel');

    tabs.on('click', function() {
      event.preventDefault();

      var thisTab = $(this),
        thisTabPanelId = thisTab.attr('aria-controls'),
        thisTabPanel = $('#' + thisTabPanelId);

      tabs.attr('aria-selected', 'false').removeClass('is-active');
      thisTab.attr('aria-selected', 'true').addClass('is-active');
      tabPanels.attr('aria-hidden', 'true').hide();
      thisTabPanel.attr('aria-hidden', 'false').show();
     
      //HERE'S WHAT I CAN'T GET TO WORK
      if (thisTab.attr('aria-expanded') == 'true') {
        thisTab.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
        thisTab.removeClass('is-active');
        thisTabPanel.attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
      } else {
        thisTab.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
        thisTab.addClass('is-active');
        thisTabPanel.attr('aria-hidden', 'false');

      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tablist {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab.is-active {
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: gray;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="tablist" role="tablist">
    <li><a class="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="panel">
    <p>PANEL 1 Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>PANEL 2 Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>PANEL 3 Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make condition that will check for  active classes and aria's at start no need for another if, just hide all panels, remove classes and reset area if its already clicked. If not do as you did before:

```
  if (thisTab.attr('aria-selected') == "false") {
    tabs.attr('aria-selected', 'false').removeClass('is-active');
    thisTab.attr('aria-selected', 'true').addClass('is-active');
    tabPanels.attr('aria-hidden', 'true').hide();
    thisTabPanel.attr('aria-hidden', 'false').show();
  } else {
     tabPanels.hide().attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
     thisTab.attr('aria-selected', 'false').removeClass('is-active') 
  }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.tablist li').attr('role', 'presentation');
  $('.tablist li a').attr({
    "aria-selected": "false",
    "role": "tab",
    "tabindex": "0"
  });


  $('.tablist__panel').attr({
    "aria-hidden": "true",
    "role": "tabpanel"
  });


  $('.tab').attr('id', function(IDcount) {
    return 'tab' + IDcount;
  });

  $('.tab').attr('href', function(IDcount) {
    return '#panel' + IDcount;
  });

  $('.tab').attr('aria-controls', function(IDcount) {
    return 'panel' + IDcount;
  });

  $('.panel').attr('id', function(IDcount) {
    return 'panel' + IDcount;
  });

  $('.panel').attr('aria-labelledby', function(IDcount) {
    return 'tab' + IDcount;
  });


  $(".panel").hide();


  $(function() {

    // Cache selectors
    var tabs = $('.tablist li a'),
      tabPanels = $('.panel');

    tabs.on('click', function() {
      event.preventDefault();

      var thisTab = $(this),
        thisTabPanelId = thisTab.attr('aria-controls'),
        thisTabPanel = $('#' + thisTabPanelId);

      if (thisTab.attr('aria-selected') == "false") {
        tabs.attr('aria-selected', 'false').removeClass('is-active');
        thisTab.attr('aria-selected', 'true').addClass('is-active');
        tabPanels.attr('aria-hidden', 'true').hide();
        thisTabPanel.attr('aria-hidden', 'false').show();
      } else {
        // here is code to reset all if tab is clicked again
        tabPanels.hide().attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
        thisTab.attr('aria-selected', 'false').removeClass('is-active')
      }



    });

  });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tablist {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab.is-active {
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: gray;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="tablist" role="tablist">
    <li><a class="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="panel">
    <p>PANEL 1 Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>PANEL 2 Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>PANEL 3 Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help! There's just one small bug. When you open a panel and then close it, all of the panels show aria-hidden="false". Do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: @Charly Sorry had a bit of trouble following whats going on in whole code. Juts replace         `tabPanels.hide().attr('aria-hidden', 'false');`
 with `tabPanels.hide(); ` Or what every you want to do with that line, or set it to true...

Comment: thanks that solves that issue. Sorry about my messy code, but now after closing the panel, the `aria-hidden` attribute of that panel doesn't change back to `true`.

Comment: @Charly But I just told you where is that line of code, so you can do what ever you need on that line, if you need them all closed and set to true just do: `tabPanels.hide().attr('aria-hidden', 'true');` I edited the code and fiddle. I believe now is how you need it.